# Django: How to monitor time specified in Model class and do some actions when current time is equal to the one specified in Model?

Tags: django

I have Model "Task" and DateTimeField "deadline" in it. How can I monitor current time and execute some actions (like sending notifications to user, that own that task) when there is, for example, 1 hour left to deadline, or deadline has already come?
  I'm using Django 2.0. 
  I've already read about Celery, but I'm not sure whether it is an appropriate solution for such task.
 I'll be glad to hear your opinions.

Comment: You can use celery beat .. So your beat scheduler will run on periodic intervals and check task deadlines (and you can send notifications base on the conditions).

Comment: OK, I'll try that. Thanks. But would it be efficient to iterate over all objects of "Task" model very often (for example, every 1-2 minutes) ?